# Error in calling unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I try to call function from a library to get some information about the machine. However I get an exception SystemLoadException: Type IODBPSD_3 from GetAlmMsg, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null could not be read, there is an object on the 4th position, which is incorrectly rounded or covered by an unobject array.Could you please give an advice what to do? Unfortunatelly I do not understand the logic of the class IODBPSD_3 at all. Thank you very much for any help.

Radek

```
public Focas1.IODBPSD_3 prmData = new Focas1.IODBPSD_3();//my call
```

....

//attachment to the FOCAS library for the machine - not my code

```
public class Focas1
{
    ...

    public const short MAX_AXIS = 8;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public class IODBPSD_3
    {
        [ FieldOffset( 0 )]
        public short   datano ;    /* data number */
        [ FieldOffset( 2 )]
        public short   type ;      /* axis number */
        [ FieldOffset( 4 ),
        MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=MAX_AXIS)]
        public byte[] cdatas = new byte[MAX_AXIS];
        [ FieldOffset( 4 ),
        MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=MAX_AXIS)]
        public short[] idatas = new short[MAX_AXIS];
        [ FieldOffset( 4 ),
        MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=MAX_AXIS)]
        public int[] ldatas = new int[MAX_AXIS];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I absolutely do not understand. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @GrantThomas: At least sometimes, you can  (`FieldOffset` allows you to make unions).  However, I'm not sure about arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in compilation. I created 32b processor and the program is working now.